# grep process is changing it's PID continously

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, grep

I am using grep to find some 'abcd' in large file. So it is running for quite some time but the PID of this process is changing continuously. I am not able to understand why ? Here is the sample top output:

```
PID   USER  PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
31824 rmkd  20   0  100m  976  780 R 98.4  0.0   0:12.18 grep
31825 rmkd  20   0  100m  968  780 R 98.4  0.0   0:09.46 grep

31909 rmkd  20   0  100m  976  780 R 96.8  0.0   0:04.14 grep
31898 rmkd  20   0  100m  976  780 R 92.8  0.0   0:06.80 grep

31909 rmkd  20   0  100m  976  780 R 96.6  0.0   0:12.25 grep
31941 rmkd  20   0  100m  968  780 R 36.2  0.0   0:01.09 grep

32017 rmkd  20   0  100m  964  780 R 98.9  0.0   0:05.63 grep
32030 rmkd  20   0  100m  976  780 R 66.4  0.0   0:02.00 grep
```

Processes:

```
[rmkd@sfskml ~]$ ps -ef|grep grep
rmkd   817 25833 97 15:07 ?        00:00:05 grep -w 172.23.7.75? /opt/dump_1.txt
rmkd   818  6621 93 15:07 ?        00:00:02 grep -w 172.30.124.137? /opt/dump_1.txt
```

Any ideas on this issue ? Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Post an exact grep command you use.

Comment: Command: grep -w 172.23.7.75? /opt/dump_1.txt. You can find same command under Processes heading in my question as well,thank you.

Comment: Not relevant to the main question but note `grep` treats this `172.30.124.137?` string as a regular expression where dots have non-literal meaning. Since it looks like it includes an IP address I suspect your search *may* not be exactly what you intended. In this particular case it may not matter (it obviously depends on the file content), but in general you should pay attention (hint: `grep -F`).

Comment: Ohh my bad, thanks. Any ideas on the actual question as well ?